# Property of expected hitting time in Markov chains

Tags: probability, markov-chains, conditional-expectation, stopping-times

Giving the probability space with states $i\in \Omega$, the conditional probability of starting at $i$ is $\mathbb{P}_i = \mathbb{P}(.|X_0=i)$.

Giving $A\in \Omega$ , let's define the hitting time : $H^{A} : \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb{N}$ :
$$H^{A}(\omega) = \{\text{inf } n, X_n(\omega) \in A\}$$

I've seen many texts mentioned (also in MSE) 
$$\mathbb{E}_i[H^A|X_1=j] = 1 + \mathbb{E}_j[H^A]$$
by simply saying it is the Markov property. The Markov property as I understood is by shifting 1 the Markov chain, we again have the same Markov chain. So I don't understand where the **1** come from.

Though I understand the intuition, that is the expected time to hit $A$ knowing $\{X_1=j,X_0=i\}$ is 1 plus the expected time to hit $A$ (re-)starting at $\{X_0=j\}$

Can someone help please, with a rigorous mathematical proof.

Answer (score 0):

The addition of 1 is taking into account that it takes time $1$ to go from $i$ to $j$ in the first place. Without this term, the expected time would just be zero whenever $A$ is reachable from $i$.

Comment: Thanks Ian, I understand this idea. But I asked for a mathematical writting of that.

Comment: @ctNGUYEN Consider each realization $X(\omega)$ such that $X_0(\omega)=i,X_1(\omega)=j$ whose time to hit $A$ is $n$. The "restarted" realization with $Y_k=X_{k+1}$ instead hits $A$ in time $n-1$. The second expectation is essentially over these "restarted" realizations, so you have to add $1$ to it to get the same thing you started with. What I just said can now be written out in symbols in an essentially direct translation.

Answer (score 0):

For any state $i\notin A$, note that $E_i[H^A]=\sum_{n=1}^\infty nP_i(H^A=n)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sum_{j\notin A}P_i(H^A=n, X_1=j)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sum_{j\in A}P_i(H^A=n,X_1=j)$

Now observe if $j\in A$, then $P_i(H^A=n,X_1=j)=0$ if $n>1$ and $=P_i(H^A=1,X_1=j)=P_i(X_1=j)=p(i,j)$ for $n=1$.

Hence $\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sum_{j\in A}P_i(H^A=n,X_1=j)=\sum_{j\in A}P_i(X_1=j)=P_i(X_1\in A)$.

Further if $j\notin A$ then by Markov property, $P_i(H^A=n,X_1=j)=P_i(X_1=j)P_j(H^A=n-1)=p(i,j)P_j(H^A=n-1)$

Writing all these into $E_i(H^A)$ we get $E_i(H^A)=P_i(X_1\in A)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty n\sum_{j\notin A}p(i,j)P_j(H^A=n-1)=P_i(X_1\in A)+\sum_{j\notin A}\sum_{n=1}^\infty (n+1)P_j(H^A=n)=P_i(X_1\in A)+\sum_{j\notin A}p(i,j)E_j(H^A)+\sum_{j\notin A}p(i,j)=1+\sum_{j\notin A}p(i,j)E_j(H^A) $

So this is the general expression. Try to get your statement by imitaing the above arguments.